# Why does the entire page jump when an input is selected in Mobile Safari?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I have a fixed form that is layered on top of the body using fixed positioning.

This full screen takeover approach works fine on Chrome and Safari desktop, but on mobile it is shifting the entire page in order to compensate for the keyboard appearing. Wondering if this is fixable *without* JS.

```
      <!--CSS-->
      .test-form {
          background-color: #fff;
          padding: 40px;
          color: #333;
          position: relative;
      }

      ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
          display: none; 
      }

      .test-form.open {
          top: 0;
          margin: 0;
          position: fixed;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          top: 0;
          z-index: 200;
          border: 1px solid red;
          background-color: #ddd;
          overflow: hidden;
      }

      .test-form label {
          display: block;
      }

      .test-form input {
          display: block;
      }

      .test-form.open .test-form__content {
          position: absolute;
          top: 10px;
          bottom: 10px;
          left: 20px;
          right: 20px;
          padding: 20px;
          border: 1px solid yellow;
          width: auto;
          height: auto;
          background-color: #eee;
          overflow-y: scroll;
      }
```

```
    <!--TEST FORM-->

    <div class="test-form open">
        <div class="test-form__content">

                <div class="filler">
                    <p>
                          "I Want You Back"

                          Uh-huh huh huhhh
                          Let me tell ya now
                          Uh-huh
                          (Mmhhmmm)

                          When I had you to myself, I didn't want you around
                          Those pretty faces always made you stand out in a crowd
                          But someone picked you from the bunch, one glance was all it took
                          Now it's much too late for me to take a second look

                          Oh baby, I need one more chance, hah
                          I tell you that I love you
                          Baby, oh! Baby, oh! Baby, oh!
                          I want you back!
                          I want you back!
                          [Fade out]
                    </p>
                </div>

                <form>
                    <label>Input One</label>
                    <input type="text" name="one" placeholder="Input Here">
                    <br>
                    <label>Input Two</label>
                    <input type="text" name="two" placeholder="Input Here">
                    <br>
                    <label>Input Three</label>
                    <input type="text" name="three" placeholder="Input Here">
                    <br>
                    <label>Input Four</label>
                    <input type="text" name="four" placeholder="Input Here">
                    <br>
                    <label>Input Five</label>
                    <input type="text" name="five" placeholder="Input Here">
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h1>footer</h1>
</body>
```

I have seen the [article on focus jumping](https://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios) and other issues with using fixed elements in iOS Safari, but I have not been able to come up with a solution.

JSFiddle below (preview the raw results iOS simulator and select different inputs, you will see the app jumping up and down):

https://jsfiddle.net/a01tnona/

View a screengrab:

http://cl.ly/1C0S153C0R0J

Comment: Isn't that for the pop up keyboard?